# How to compare direct and mediated effect of X on Y in a partial mediation situation?

Tags: regression, mediation

[image]

image credit:@Jeromy Anglim

If I've proven that these is a partial mediated relation in the image above, is these an appropriate way to compare the effect of 1.independent var on dependent var with(C) 2.independent var through mediator var on dependent var (A -B)?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to test the null hypothesis that $AB = C$. This is kind of a weird hypothesis, because it implies that the effect through the mediator is exactly half of the total effect. What substantive question this answers seems ambiguous to me.

A straightforward way would be to bootstrap it. In each bootstrapped sample, compute $AB-C$. Then you can get the confidence interval using one of the several ways to do so from bootstraps. If the interval contains 0, then there is not enough evidence to claim that the indirect and direct effect differ in magnitude.

Comment: I very much appreciate your insights, I haven't thought that way before. But since I'm tacking this question for a journal article that sits more in social sciences side, I am not sure the rather ML approach will be accepted(though I do think it is a great way to tackle it and there is a fine line). Would you say it is wrong to compare A-C v.s AxB -C without bootstrapping?

Comment: Social scientists are definitely comfortable with bootstrapping. Bootstrapping is considered the recommended way of estimating standard errors for indirect effects in mediation, so this would not be out of the ordinary. As I mentioned, the only thing out of the ordinary would be the choice of the null hypothesis.